# SSIS Split String address

Tags: string, ssis, split

I have a column which is made up of addresses as show below.

Address

- 1 Reid Street, Manchester, M1 2DF
- 12 Borough Road, London, E12,2FH
- 15 Jones Street, Newcastle, Tyne & Wear, NE1 3DN

etc .. etc....

I am wanting to split this into different columns to import into my SQL database.  I have been trying to use Findstring to seperate by the comma but am having trouble when some addresses have more "sections" than others.  ANy ideas whats the best way to go about this?

Many THanks

Comment: What are is/are your datasource(s)? Depending on those, it might be easier to split the address before getting it into SSIS

Comment: i was thinking this myself. its coming from excel so can split into columns if needed to was just trying to make all the other processes change in SSIS at the same time

Comment: If possible, as it seems to be, just keep the processing in the excel. It is easier to handle null columns than doing that kind of splitting on SSIS. That said, it is still possible, but you will get a rather large data flow for such an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

This is a requirements specification problem, not an implementation problem.  The more you can afford to assume about the format of the addresses, the more detailed parsing you will be able to do; the other side of the same coin is that the less you will assume about the structure of the address, the fewer incorrect parses you will be blamed for.

It is crucial to determine whether you will only need to process UK postal emails, or whether worldwide addresses may occur.

Based on your examples, certain parts of the address seem to be always present, but please check [this resource](http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats/united-kingdom/) to determine whether they are really required in all UK email addresses.

If you find a match between the depth of parsing that you need, and the assumptions that you can safely make, you should be able to keep parsing by comma indexes (`FINDSTRING`); determine some components starting from the left, and some starting from the right of the string; and keep all that remains as an unparsed body.

It may also well happen that you will find that your current task is a mission impossible, especially in connection with international postal addresses.  This is why most websites and other data collectors require the entry of postal address in an already parsed form by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent points raised by Hanika. Some of your parsing will depend on what your target destination looks like. As an ignorant yank, based on Hanika's link, I'd think your output would look something like

- Addressee
- Organisation
- BuildingName
- BuildingAddress
- Locality
- PostTown
- Postcode
- BasicsMet (boolean indicating whether minimum criteria for a *good* address has been met.)

  - In the US, just because an address could not be properly [CASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_Accuracy_Support_System)ed doesn't mean it couldn't be delivered - cip, my grandparent-in-laws live in enough small town that specifying their name and city is sufficient for delivery as local postal officials *know* who they are. For bulk mailings though, their address would not qualify for the bulk mailing rate and would default to first class mailing. I assume a similar scenario exists for UK mail

The general idea is for each row flowing through, you'll want to do your best to parse the data out into those buckets. The optimal solution for getting it "right" is to change the data entry method to validate and capture data into those discrete buckets. Since optimal never happens, it becomes your task to sort through the dross to find your gold.

Whilst you can write some fantastic expressions with FINDSTRING, I'd advise against it in this case as maintenance alone will drive you mad. Instead, add a Script Transformation and build your parsing logic in .NET (vb or c#). There will then be a cycle of running data through your transformation and having someone eyeball the results. If you find a new scenario, you go back and adjust your business rules. It's ugly, it's iterative and it's prone to producing results that a human wouldn't have.

Alternatives to rolling your address standardisation logic

- buy it. Eventually your business needs outpace your ability to cope with constantly changing business rules. There are plenty of vendors out there but I'm only familiar with US based ones
- upgrade to SQL Server 2012 to use [DQS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dqs/archive/2011/07/18/using-the-ssis-dqs-cleansing-component.aspx) (Data Quality Services). You'll probably still need to buy a product to build out your knowledge base but you could offload the business rule making task to a domain expert ("Hey you, you make peanuts an hour. Make sure all the addresses coming out of this look like addresses" was how they covered this in the beginning of one of my jobs).